# PHP array_keys multiple levels

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have array1 like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => 123
[1] => 456
[2] => 789
)
```

And array 2 like this

```
 Array
 (

 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => some text
        [1] => 888
        [2] => some
        [3] => text
    )
  [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => some text
        [1] => 123
        [2] => some
        [3] => text
    )
  [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => some text
        [1] => 999
        [2] => some
        [3] => text
    )   
   [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => some text
        [1] => Array
            (
                [1] => 456
                [2] => 789
            )
        [2] => some
        [3] => text
    ) 
   [4] => Array
    (
        [0] => some text
        [1] => 123
        [2] => some
        [3] => text
    )   
  )
```

I am checking only 1. column of second array and finding values that match values from first array. This is my code:

```
 $test=array();

 $xcol = array_column($array2, 1);
 foreach( $array1 as $key => $value ) {
 if( ($foundKey = array_keys($xcol, $value)) !== false ) {
 $rrt=$foundKey;
 foreach($rrt as $rte){
  $test[]=$array2[$rte];
}
}
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($test);
echo "</pre>";
```

It is working and giving me proper results but it does not check for all levels. Can anybody please point me what am I doing wrong?
My output is:

```
Array
 (

  [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => some text
        [1] => 123
        [2] => some
        [3] => text
    )
   [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => some text
        [1] => 123
        [2] => some
        [3] => text
    )   
   )
```

And desired output is:

```
Array
 (

  [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => some text
        [1] => 123
        [2] => some
        [3] => text
    )
   [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => some text
        [1] => Array
            (
                [1] => 456
                [2] => 789
            )
        [2] => some
        [3] => text
    ) 
   [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => some text
        [1] => 123
        [2] => some
        [3] => text
    )   
   )
```

Comment: you could use the [`recursiveArrayIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

Comment: @mister martin, can you give me some hint how would I use than array_key search to find value and still output everything else sub array contain? I have never used recursiveArrayIterator before so I am a bit confused

Comment: so your problem is you don't get 456 and 789?

Comment: Yes, I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

create a loop which loop your `$array2` which holds datas you wanted to get whos values match in first array `$array1`

```
foreach($array2 as $data) {
```

Inside loop create another loop which loop your indexes

```
    foreach($data as  $value) {
```

But before than create a condition if your index value is array loop it and check it it's index value is match in any indexes from `$array1` use php function `in_array` for that

```
        if (gettype($value) == "array") {
            foreach($value as $val) {
                if (in_array($val, $array1) ) {
                    $result[] = $data;
```

Then if you find it just stop the loop using `break` to avoid duplication

```
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Else you just directly use in_array

```
        } else if (in_array($value, $array1)) {
            $result[] = $data;
        }
    }
}
```

Just grab the code here in [**Demo**](https://eval.in/705626)

Help it helps just mark it answer if you are satisfied to it

Answer (score 1):

Lets make a recursive method for this. What is recursion you ask? Well it is simply a method that calls it self.

```
<?php
$array1 = array(123,456,789);
$array2 = array(
    array(
         "some text"
        , 888
        , "some"
        , "text"
    ),
    array(
        "some text"
        ,123
        ,"some"
        ,"text"
    ),
    array(
        "some text"
        ,999
        ,"some"
        ,"text"
    ),  
    array(
        "some text"
        ,array(456,789)
        ,"some"
        ,"text"
    ),
    array(
        "another text"
        ,123
        ,"some"
        ,"text"
    )   
);
$final = array();
foreach($array1 as $needle){
    foreach($array2 as $haystack){
        if(find($needle,$haystack)){
            $final[] = $haystack;
        }
    }
}

print_r($final);

function find($needle, $haystack){
    $result = false;
    foreach ($haystack as $value) {
        if(is_array($value)){
            $result = find($needle, $value);
        } else {
            if($needle == $value){
                $result = true;
            } 
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: @codexy I just want to make sure you only want the key of the top level array that has a match in it?

Comment: Yes, match would be 3 (in this specific case), and that is all I need, so than I can retrieve values from it.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6eb4f61b9a9fbd8773a93e18ed2c82ede2c41eb8

Comment: This is what I have now, but I am missing 3.column in output from array2 which is match also

Comment: @codexy there is still an issue where the results will have 4 duplicating the array for 456 and 789. You could just store keys of arrays and clean up dups in that.